# Mongodb query join optimization

Tags: sql, mongodb, join

Lets say I have 3 collections:

```
Grandparents
{
 _id:1,
 name:old foo
}

Parents
{
_id:2,
grandparentId:1,
name: foo
}
Person
{
_id: 3,
parentId:2,
name: youngfoo
}
```

How do i optimize a query to find all person where person's grandparent's name = x?

Name is not unique in this case.

What i can think of so far:
1. Query all grandparents with name = x
2. Query all parents where grandparent ids == grandparent ids gotten from step 1
3. Query all persons where parent ids == parent ids gotten from step 2.

Doesn't feel very efficient. Can mongodb experts out there help me? Thanks!

Comment: You have modeled your NoSQL database in relational way. Try Embedding the documents. If you want to have relational approach just try RDMS

Comment: I thought of using embedded way before but the thing is i also need the ability to filter parents and person...for example find all person with name = y

Comment: @Undefined_variable That's plainly the wrong approach. [Embedding arbitrary numbers of documents is the root of all evil](http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/). An [array of ancestors](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/) or materialized path is by far the better approach.

Comment: hi Markus, I've read about ancestor/materialized path, but doesn't that mean in my case, that person should also store grandparentsId ? But If I need to filter on grandparent's and parent's name, I still have to do the 3 steps that I outlined above if my query is like: get all Person whose grandparent's name == x and parent's name == y

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this. I did not test this query, but this is what i would try in your place. This is only possible on 3.6 mongodb, because it supports multiple joins. The idea is to join all 3 collections. First join is Parents and Person by Parents id, and Persons "parentsId". Second join is Parents and Grandparents. Then you filter out by grandparent name and you will get a document that contains that grandparent, his son (parent), and his grandson(person). Then you just project the person.

```
    db.Parents.aggregate([
       {
          $lookup:{
             from:"Person",
             localField:"_id",
             foreignField:"parentId",
             as:"Person"
          }
       },
       {
          $unwind:"$Person"
       },
       {
          $lookup:{
             from:"Grandparents",
             localField:"grandparentId",
             foreignField:"_id",
             as:"Grandparents"
          }
       },
       {
          $unwind:"$Grandparents"
       },
       {$match:{Grandparents.name:"x"}},
       {$project:{Person.name:1,Person._id:1}}
}])
```

I think this will do the trick