# MongoDB why use an embedded list instead of separate collection?

Tags: performance, mongodb, collections

Assuming we have a server with large enough RAM, why should we worry about extra querying required when we use separate collections instead of embedded list of objects? Since queries will be really fast, would it be worth it to store objects as embedded list?

Comment: Should you design your database model based on Hardware? The answer is NO! If you can minimize the number of queries why not do it? You design an application but you never know the machine that will host it.

Comment: Here is a guide giving some hints on how to model relationships in mongodb : https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: For my project, i think using nested embedded lists can be much more complicated, query-wise. Can you pls look at my other question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736372/mongodb-query-join-optimization

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a [16MB size limit for BSON documents in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size). So when depending on the data model, you impose an artificial limit to what can be stored.
2. Depending on your [storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/faq/storage/#storage-engine-fundamentals), increasing the document size frequently can cause the document moved within the data files, which is a rather costly operation you *really* want to prevent
3. With complicated data models, queries tend to get more complicated, leading to problem, as you can see often see here on SO. Complicated queries are not necessarily faster.
4. Usually, embedded documents stem from the fact that developers are used to SQL JOINs and want their data all within one query. But if you boil it down, usually you have questions like

   > For a **given** `X`, what are the `Y`s belonging to it?

   So usually you already have `X`. There is no need to prematurely load data you never need in the majority of cases. Think of an overview page of Xs where you select the `X` you want to see the according `Y`s. Even with a pagination of 10, 9/10 of the data loaded would be useless if you had all the data embedded. Fun fact: This applies to SQL, too – though nobody seems to care about *real* optimizations nowadays.

This is the summary of [my blog post "The problem with overembedding"](http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/), where you find an in-detail explanation of the points mentioned above.

Comment: so Markus, when list of objects is finite/very little 20-30 max objects lets say, is it better to store it as embedded objects even though I have needs to query the objects in the nested list?

Comment: @user1955934 That is _very_ hard to say without knowing your use cases, the size of the embedded documents, the application, and what not. In general, if you are not absolutely positively sure that you need the embedded documents every time you load the containing document **and**   that under no circumstances whatsoever the number and/or size of the embedded documents can possibly ever reach the size limit, I'd suggest to avoid embedding.